# Wordpress Qtranslate keep don't keep lang on word search

Tags: wordpress, search, qtranslate

On my wordpress blog I installed Qtranslate plugin and it is working fine for my pages and posts.It adds **lang=en** at the end of all my pages and posts urls.

The problem is that in my top bar I have a search form :

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
<input type="search" results=""class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>" />
</form>
```

and Qtranslate is not adding its lang parameter here when I search for a word:

```
http://myblog/?s=word-to-look-for
```

So that whenever I search for a word and I get the results page the blog language switch back to default (en_US)

How could I solve that?

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you switch your site to the other (and better for SEO), url rewrite where it adds the language code at the end?

Works for here http://www.specialolympics.ca/fr/?s=test

The other option would be to add a hidden field to the search form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="<?php echo qtrans_getLanguage(); ?>">
```

Comment: Great,this is working! I want to ask you another tip.On my search result page I have :"<?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'myblog' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?> " How could I achieve to have this translated as well?

Comment: Try this (in place of :fr, use the language code you need)  
`<?php printf( _e( '<!--:en-->Search Results for<!--:--><!--:fr-->Translated text<!--:-->: %s', 'myblog' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?>`

Comment: Thanks it works! there's any way I could make use of .mo files while using Qtranslate?

Comment: It does support and use them, but it's not something I've ever dealt with. Check this for some info: http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3#p7